# SQL turn multiple results into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that returns a list of GUIDs like this:

```
92bca6ba-0174-4d80-b701-8bed4b2673e0
917399f2-05d7-42ff-b84e-5f8395c8e8fd
```

What I need the results to be is one string of text:

```
'92bca6ba-0174-4d80-b701-8bed4b2673e0', '917399f2-05d7-42ff-b84e-5f8395c8e8fd'
```

I've looked into several options but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Search for `LISTAGG/GROUP_CONCAT/string_agg`

Comment: I have used that for Oracle SQL, but I don't think it works for MS SQL?

Comment: `FOR XML + STUFF` is the way to go.